# Oracle query problem

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Please let me know why this query is not working together. They are working separately:

```
(  (select item_name,
           sum(p_qty)
      from stock 
     where p_date between '08/06/2010' and '08/07/2010'
  group by item_name) -
(   select item_name, 
           sum(p_r_qty)
      from stock 
     where p_r_date between '08/06/2010' and '08/07/2010' 
  group by item_name))
```

Comment: I'd like to help, but what are you trying to accomplish?  Example data and expected output please.

Comment: what is that `-` you've got there? Are you trying to subtract the queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select item_name, 
           sum(p_qty) ,
           sum(p_r_qty)
      from stock  
     where p_date between '08/06/2010' and '08/07/2010' 
group by item_name
```

is this what you want ?

```
select item_name, 
           sum(p_qty)-sum(p_r_qty)
      from stock  
     where p_date between '08/06/2010' and '08/07/2010' 
group by item_name
```